# Getting different base64 encoding while porting to PHP from C#

Tags: c#, php

I don't know C# and I must port a small function into PHP. I broke down all the code into a simple example showing the issue.

Here is the C# portion where a sha1 hash is being base64 encoded:

```
HMACSHA1 hmacTest = new HMACSHA1();
hmacTest.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(identity);

byte[] sha1 = hmacTest.ComputeHash(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 86, 107, 192, 162, 99, 111, 110, 102});

Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(sha1.Select(b => b.ToString("x2"))));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(sha1, Base64FormattingOptions.None));
// sha1: 02628928a3a2ab831a769f2fd64a3bae4036265f
// encoded: AmKJKKOiq4Madp8v1ko7rkA2Jl8=
```

Here is the PHP portion showing a different result, though the sha1 matches

```
$key = base64_decode($identity);
$data = call_user_func_array("pack", array_merge(array("C*"), array(0, 0, 0, 0, 86, 107, 192, 162, 99, 111, 110, 102)));

$sha1 = hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $key);

var_dump($sha1, base64_encode($sha1));
// sha1: 02628928a3a2ab831a769f2fd64a3bae4036265f
// encoded: MDI2Mjg5MjhhM2EyYWI4MzFhNzY5ZjJmZDY0YTNiYWU0MDM2MjY1Zg==
```

I must modify the PHP portion to match. I'm thinking it's an encoding issue. Or possibly that in C# ToBase64String is not being passed a string version of the sha1. How would I replicate this in PHP if that is why it's different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your C# code sha1 is a byte array but in your PHP code I ***think*** your sha1 is a string

So Give this snippet a try:

```
$sha1 = hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $key,TRUE);
```

with the 4th param you'll get raw binary instead of string.

Comment: Oh my, that was so easy. Forgot all about the 4th param. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you for this! I found this answer after 4 hours of digging around and Googleing.. I had a similar problem which drove me bananas :)